# Remove the main domain from a list of subdomains

Tags: regex, bash, kali-linux

How to remove the main domain from a list of subdomains
for example if i have a file contains

```
www.example.com
sub.examle.com
sub2.example.com
examle.com.ar
example.com
```

I want to extract only

```
sub.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

I try
`grep -v '^www.example.com' file.txt`
how can i get sub domains

Comment: Why is www.example.com not in your output?

Comment: How are you choosing to define "main domain" vs. "subdomain" for your specific use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First use Perl regular expression by using the `P` option.
- `^(?!www\.)` get all the strings that do not begin with a www. (`(?!www\.)` negative lookahead).
- `\w+\.` matches any number of word characters (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) followed by a period.
- `\w{4,}` match more than 4 word characters.

```
grep -P '^(?!www\.)\w+\.\w{4,}' file.txt
#> sub.examle.com
#> sub2.example.com
```